# Finding Contiguous Areas of Bits in 2D Bit Array

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

### The Problem

I have a bit array which represents a 2-dimensional "map" of "tiles". This image provides a graphical example of the bits in the bit array:

[image: Bit Array Example]

I need to determine how many contiguous "areas" of bits exist in the array. In the example above, there are two such contiguous "areas", as illustrated here:

[image: Contiguous Areas]

Tiles must be located directly N, S, E or W of a tile to be considered "contiguous". Diagonally-touching tiles do not count.

### What I've Got So Far

Because these bit arrays can become relatively large (several MB in size), I have intentionally avoided using any sort of recursion in my algorithm.

The pseudo-code is as follows:

```
LET S BE SOURCE DATA ARRAY
LET C BE ARRAY OF IDENTICAL LENGTH TO SOURCE DATA USED TO TRACK "CHECKED" BITS
FOREACH INDEX I IN S
    IF C[I] THEN 
        CONTINUE 
    ELSE
        SET C[I]
        IF S[I] THEN
            EXTRACT_AREA(S, C, I)

EXTRACT_AREA(S, C, I):
    LET T BE TARGET DATA ARRAY FOR STORING BITS OF THE AREA WE'RE EXTRACTING
    LET F BE STACK OF TILES TO SEARCH NEXT
    PUSH I UNTO F
    SET T[I]
    WHILE F IS NOT EMPTY
        LET X = POP FROM F
        IF C[X] THEN 
            CONTINUE
        ELSE
            SET C[X]
            IF S[X] THEN
                PUSH TILE NORTH OF X TO F
                PUSH TILE SOUTH OF X TO F
                PUSH TILE WEST OF X TO F
                PUSH TILE EAST OF X TO F
                SET T[X]
    RETURN T
```

[image: Animation of My Algorithm]

### What I Don't Like About My Solution

- Just to run, it requires two times the memory of the bitmap array it's processing.
- While extracting an "area", it uses three times the memory of the bitmap array.
- Duplicates exist in the "tiles to check" stack - which seems ugly, but not worth avoiding the way I have things now.

### What I'd Like To See

- Better memory profile
- Faster handling of large areas

---

### Solution / Follow-Up

I re-wrote the solution to explore the edges only (per @hatchet 's suggestion).

This was very simple to implement - and eliminated the need to keep track of "visited tiles" completely.

Based on three simple rules, I can traverse the edges, track min/max x & y values, and complete when I've arrived at the start again.

Here's the demo with the three rules I used:

[image: Solution]

Comment: What is the runtime of your algo?

Comment: One more question what is the end result of the algo, it's not a flood-fill right

Comment: +1 for detail and pictures. Offtopic, how did you create the third image?

Comment: @aaronman - yes, basically. Although I hadn't thought about it that way since it's not part of a "painting" program... but now that you mention it, I should have searched for something along those lines before posting the question.

Comment: @vidit - http://gifmaker.me

Comment: Well the best way to do a flood fill is with a breadth first search to avoid the recursion

Comment: Is the 'area' the rectangle that encloses the shape (the bold line in your diagram), or just the points occupied by the shape? If area is the enclosing rectangle, how do you want to handle areas that overlap - i.e. a small area could be partially or entirely within the area of a larger irregular shape?

Comment: @hatchet - It's the area enclosing the rectangle. I was going to handle areas that overlap as a second phase because my rules for "joining" them are dependent on my specific implementation of the bit arrays (I'm using 32-bit ints, and I'll join them even if they overlap on "32-bit boundaries" - so even if the rectangles don't "overlap" directly, they may when taken in 32-bit chunks.)

Comment: @Steve - if you just want the enclosing rectangle, could you just walk the perimeter until you arrive back to the start, recording the min and max x and y as you go. That would require little additional space.

Comment: @hatchet - That's a GREAT point. I think you're on to something there!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One approach would be a perimeter walk. 
Given a starting point anywhere along the edge of the shape, remember that point.

Start the bounding box as just that point.

Walk the perimeter using a clockwise rule set - if the point used to get to the current point was above, then first look right, then down, then left to find the next point on the shape perimeter. This is kind of like the simple strategy of solving a maze where you continuously follow a wall and always bear to the right.

Each time you visit a new perimeter point, expand the bounding box if the new point is outside it (i.e. keep track of the min and max x and y.

Continue until the starting point is reached.

Cons: if the shape has lots of single pixel 'filaments', you'll be revisiting them as the walk comes back.

Pros: if the shape has large expanses of internal occupied space, you never have to visit them or record them like you would if you were recording visited pixels in a flood fill.

So, conserves space, but in some cases at the expense of time.

**Edit**

As is so often the case, this problem is known, named, and has multiple algorithmic solutions. The problem you described is called Minimum Bounding Rectangle. One way to solve this is using [Contour Tracing](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/alg.html). The method I described above is in that class, and is  called [Moore-Neighbor Tracing](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/moore.html) or [Radial Sweep](http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/ray.html). The links I've included for them discuss them in detail and point out a problem I hadn't caught. Sometimes you'll revisit the start point *before* you have traversed the entire perimeter. If your start point is for instance somewhere along a single pixel 'filament', you will revisit it before you're done, and unless you consider this possibility, you'll stop prematurely. The website I linked to talks about ways to address this stopping problem. Other pages at that website also talk about two other algorithms: Square Tracing, and Theo Pavlidis's Algorithm. One thing to note is that these consider diagonals as contiguous, whereas you don't, but that should just something that can be handled with minor modifications to the basic algorithms.

An alternative approach to your problem is [Connected-component labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling). For your needs though, this may be a more time expensive solution than you require.

Additional resource:

[Moore Neighbor Contour Tracing Algorithm in C++](http://www.thebigblob.com/moore-neighbor-contour-tracing-algorithm-in-c/)

Comment: Does this account for an outline with empty space inside?

Comment: @aaronman - I thought a little about that and some other cases that might thwart this strategy. The possibility of that is important to consider and rule out. I haven't thoroughly done that. I think enclosed empty spaces would be ok. They don't effect the bounding box, and as long as you enter the shape to your starting point on an exterior perimeter point, I think it would just go around the empty space.

Comment: in that case good solution +1, the only thing is what the OP wants indeed a flood-fill variant I wasn't 100% sure

Comment: I realize my decision to select this as the answer is based completely on my desired outcome - which I may have failed to fully explain in the question... so I'm not saying this will be the best answer for anyone looking to "find contiguous areas of bits in a 2d bit array"... but, for my specific purposes, this seems ideal. Enclosed empty spaces are OK, etc - plus, the likely "shapes" I'll encounter will be best handled by this idea (large amounts of occupied space with "jagged" edges around the perimeter. Thanks!

Comment: @Steve - I've edited my answer to provide some additional important information.

Comment: Thanks @hatchet! Good info. Yes, I had considered the "single pixel filaments" (as you put it) - I handled it be using decimal coordinates to track my current location along the perimeter instead of merely the index of the cell. Not sure if that's common or not, but it worked well for me - and it completely eliminated my need to track which tiles have been "visited", etc.

Comment: @Steve - The way I was thinking to address the stopping problem was to first look one pixel in the counterclockwise direction to obtain the direction that would would arrive at the starting point when you were really done. Then during the clockwise walk, the stopping condition is when you arrive back at the start AND you arrive there from that counterclockwise pixel. Glad you were able to find a solution. How did it compare time and space-wise to your original solution?

Comment: @hatchel - actual time savings depends on the complexity of the shape in question (a rectangle being the worst-case for the old solution). In a rectangle of width x height, the old solution evaluated width x height cells. where as the new solution is only (width x 2 + height x 2). In terms of space, it's 1/3 the required space... nearly optimal as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

I actually got a question like this in an interview once.

You can pretend the array is a graph and the connected nodes are the adjacent ones. My algo would involves going 1 to the right until you find a marked node. When you find one do a breadth first search which runs in O(n) and avoids recursion. When the BFS returns keep searching from where you left off and if the node has already been marked by one of the previous BFS's you obviously don't need to search. I wasn't sure if you wanted to actually return the number of objects found, but it's easy to keep track by just incrementing a counter when you hit the first marked square.

Generally when you do a flood fill type algorithm you are placed in a spot and asked to fill. Since this is finding all the filled regions one way you would want to optimize it is to avoid rechecking the already marked nodes from previous BFS's, unfortunately at the moment I cannot think of a way to do that.

One hacky way to reduce memory consumption would be too store a `short[][]` instead of a boolean. Then use this scheme to avoid making a whole second 2d-array

> unmarked = 0, marked = 1, checked and unmarked = 3, checked and marked = 3

This way you can check the status of an entry by its value and avoid making a second array.

Comment: @Steve thanks, I think the runtime is still O(n), I wish I could think of a way to completely skip over parts I have already labelled as an object and improve the run time a bit

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the code to try and determine the runtime, but I'm out of practice a bit, and I think it may be O(n) as-is... but at this point I think my bigger issue is the memory profile - and I'd probably be willing to give up some processing efficiency to reduce the amount of memory used - although I can't think of how to do that at the moment and have it be a compromise. Seems like I have to choose between terrible memory profile and terrible processing efficiency.

Comment: @Steve this solution is a bit hacky, but since I'm guessing booleans take the same space as integers in java use the original array as the second array. unmarked = 0, marked = 1, checked and unmarked = 3, checked and marked = 3

Comment: I'm actually using C, and storing 32-bits at a time in a single int... so my bits truly are single bits. Unfortunately, they just aren't getting any smaller than that :) I really appreciate the help, and your insightful comments.